# Javascript: How to create a bi-dimensional array with unknown length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create 2 bi-dimensional arrays as global variables in javascript like this:

```
player = [nPlayers];
helps = [nPlayers];
```

And I populate them in a `for` loop as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < nPlayers; i++) {
    j = i + 1;
    name = window.localStorage.getItem('player' + j);

    player[i] = [j, name, 0];                           
    helps[i] = [1,1,1,1];
```

Until here, everything is ok, but everytime that I do something like this:

```
var currentPlayer = 1;
player[currentPlayer][2];
```

It gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I edited the Question like you asked to

Comment: you have a typo `players[i] = [j,name,0]`, not `player[i] = [j,name,0]`, and `players[currentPlayer][2]`, or change your `players` variable to `player`

Comment: Sorry the code is right, it was me copy the code to here that mistaken me

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/48cb9a5m/, Can you make a jsfiddle that will demonstrate the error? The only thing I can think of that would cause the error is that your `nPLayers` variable is not a number above 0 and so your array never gets filled

Comment: I tried and it gets filled.